# How to shuffle eight items to approximate maximum entropy?

Tags: random, language-agnostic, combinatorics

I need to analyze 8 chemical samples repeatedly over 5 days (each sample is analyzed exactly once every day). I'd like to generate pseudo-random sample sequences for each day which achieve the following:

- avoid bias in the daily sequence position (e.g., avoid some samples being processed mostly in the morning)
- avoid repeating sample pairs over different days (e.g. `12345678` on day 1 and `87654321` on day 2)
- generally randomize the distance between two given samples from one day to the other

I may have poorly phrased the conditions above, but the general idea is to minimize systematic effects like sample cross-contamination and/or analytical drift over each day. I could just shuffle each sequence randomly, but because the number of sequences generated is small (N=5 versus 40,320 possible combinations), I'm unlikely to approach something like maximum entropy.

Any ideas? I suspect this is a common problem in analytical science which has been solved, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: Feels broad. Try to formulate it more in mathematical terms. And then also: do you really need a random result? Or can you just optimize some model with your conditions/objectives which will always result in the same output?

Comment: Analytical science, or statistics, but I wouldn't know where to look either.

Comment: This doesn't go towards solving the problem, but I'm interested: do the constraints apply over the whole five days, or would it for example be OK to have the sequence 12345678 on both day 1 and 5?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be OK. The idea would be to have something that approximates randomness, while still minimizing simple repeating patterns.

Answer (score 0):

By just thinking about:

The base metric that you may be use is the Levenshtein distances or some slightly modification (maybe

```
myDist(w1, w2) = min(levD(w1, w2), levD(w1.reversed(), w2))
```

)

Since you want to prevent near distances between any pair of days, 
the overall metric can be the sum of the any combinations of sample orders between two days.

```
Similarity = myDist(day1, day2)
           + myDist(day1, day3)
           + myDist(day1, day4)
           + myDist(day1, day5)
           + myDist(day2, day3)
           + myDist(day2, day4)
           + myDist(day2, day5)
           + myDist(day3, day4)
           + myDist(day3, day5)
           + myDist(day4, day5)
```

That still is missing, is a heuristic how to create the sample orders.

Your problem reminds me on some fastest path finding problem but with the further difficulty that each selected node influences the weights of the whole graph. So it is much harder.

Maybe a table with all `myDist`distances between each pair of the `8!` combinations can be created (its commutative, only triangular (without identity diagonal) matrix requiring (~1GB memory)) This may help speeding things up very much.

Maybe take the max from this matrix and consider each combination with value below some threshold as equally worthless to reduce the searchspace.

Build a starting set.
Use 12345678 as the fix day1 since first day does not matter. Never change this.
then repeat until n days are chose:

- adding the most distant point from current point.
- If there are multiple equal possibility, use the one, that also is most distant from the previous days.

Now iteratively improve the solution - maybe with some ruin-and-recreate-approach. You should always backup the absolute maximum you found and you are able to run as many iterations as you want (and you have time for)

1. chose (one or two) day(s) with the smallest distance sums to other days
2. maybe brute force an optimal (in terms of overall distance) combination for these two days.
3. repeat

   - If optimization stucks (only same 2 days are chosen or distance is not getting smaller at all)
   - randomly change one or two days to random orders.
   - may be totally random (beside day1) starting sets can be selected